# Hive RegEx Serde doesn't work and loads as NULL

Tags: regex, hive, create-table, hive-serde, hiveddl

I am trying to create a hive table with Serde Regex property to load the below file.

Input File:

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/t04413b/test.log
{"repoType":3,"repo":"PROD_hive","reqUser":"shdingst","evtTime":"2020-06-09 01:01:23.308"}
```

Hive create table query:

```
create external table logs3
(
repo_type  string,
repo string,
requser string,
evttime string
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
with serdeproperties (
"input.regex" = ":(.*),.*:(.*),.*:(.*),.*?:(.*)}.*"
)
stored as textfile;
```

load data inpath '/user/t04413b/test.log' into table logs3;

```
select * from logs3;
+------------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+--+
| logs3.repo_type  | logs3.repo  | logs3.requser  | logs3.evttime  |
+------------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+--+
| NULL             | NULL        | NULL           | NULL           |
```

I tested the regex in Rubular.com and it worked fine but in SerDe Regex its not working. 
Can someone please help to resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can use backticks to format code like so: ``` code ``` . This makes the question more readable

Answer (score -1):

`'}'` is a special character in regex and needs shielding:

```
"input.regex" = "^.*:(.*),.*:(.*),.*:(.*),.*?:(.*)\\}.*"
```